How to Dynamically Update JWT Bearer Options in ASP.NET Core Middleware?
I’m working on an ASP.NET Core application that uses JWT Bearer authentication. I need to dynamically update the JWT Bearer Backchannel, during runtime without restarting the application.
After the application starts, a password for a proxy is downloaded from Azure Key Vault.
This password is used to configure the Backchannel in JwtBearerOptions.
However, I’m encountering issues where changes to JwtBearerOptions are not being picked up by the middleware. I managed to make it work using
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

but this is considered an anti pattern
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidIssuer = "YourIssuer",
                ValidAudience = "YourAudience",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YourSecretKey"))
            };

            // This is what I'm trying to avoid
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            options.Backchannel = httpClientFactory.Create("Proxy");
        });

any ideas how to solve it?
I also tried, but this change does not have any effect
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // Use the backchannel dynamically by injecting the backchannel manager
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var httpClientFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                    options.Backchannel = httpClientFactory .CreateClient("Proxy");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
}


I would set the BackChannelHttpHandler, like this:
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.BackchannelHttpHandler = new BackChannelListener();
    opt.BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);         //default 60s
    ...
}

Here is a sample handler I wrote that logs all requests to the token server, but I am sure it can be adapted to add the necessary logic to tweak the request as you need.
/// <summary>
/// Backchannel listener, that will log requests made to our IdentityServer 
/// From the IdentityServer in production training class https://www.tn-data.se
/// </summary>
public class BackChannelListener : DelegatingHandler
{
    public BackChannelListener() : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BackChannelListener");
        Console.WriteLine("@@@@ SendASync: " + request.RequestUri);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var result = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        result.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ success: " + result.IsFaulted);
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ loadtime: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ url: " + request.RequestUri);

            Serilog.Log.Logger.ForContext("SourceContext", "BackChannelListener")
                              .ForContext("url", request.RequestUri)
                              .ForContext("loadtime", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms")
                              .ForContext("success", result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                              .Information("Loading IdentityServer configuration");
        });

        return result;
    }
}

}

To change the options dynamically, you could use the IoptionsMonitor service which resolved from IserviceProvider like following:
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var jwtoptionsMonitor = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions>>();
        var jwtoptions = jwtoptionsMonitor.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var httpClientFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        jwtoptions.Backchannel = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Proxy");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};

This jwtoptions could take effect after you change it.
